# 'If he is convicted, he would be taken' - Mixed conditional?

Tags: conditional-constructions, modality

Consider:

> **If he is convicted, he would be taken** to a lawful place of execution where he’d be put down in the most humane method known to science, either by hanging or by lethal injection.

Is the following some kind of mixed conditional? Why is "would" instead of "will" or "should" used in the second clause?

Comment: It is not a mixed conditional, because that type of conditional uses a past tense in the if-clause and a present tense in the main clause. http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/conditional/

Comment: @Sander I believe that most sources that adopt the conditionals 1, 2, 3 (and in some cases, also 0) would agree that this (*If he is convicted, he would be taken ...*) should be treated as a mixed conditional. Whether it is a good utterance or grammatical is another matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To begin with, forget that rubbish about "1st, 2nd, 3rd, 0, mixed conditionals". These terms do not name anything which actually exists in English; they're merely a pedagogic device for introducing learners to a small number of conditional constructions. They're what I call "baby rules": rules you give beginners to tide them over until they know enough to break them. You're a grown-up now, and all these n-conditionals can do is confuse you. Throw them away.

In formal terms you are quite right; a *realis* ('indicative') in the protasis (*IF clause, condition clause) ordinarily demands a *realis* in the apodosis (*THEN* clause, consequence clause), and an *irrealis* ('subjunctive') demands an *irrealis*:

> If he **is** convicted, he **will** be taken . . .
>   If he **were** convicted, he **would** be taken . . .

However, your example is not a formal, written utterance but quoted speech; and the use of modals in speech has been in transition for at least a century now. The line between *realis* and *irrealis* has become blurred: the past forms (*could*, *might*, *should*, *would*) have become largely divorced from what are conventionally regarded as their present forms (*can*, *may*, *shall*, *will*) and have taken on present-tense meanings which are not necessarily or entirely *irrealis*.

And this little passage addresses a situation where the line between realis and irrealis is inherently ambiguous. Rupert is employing a hypothetical but very actualizable situation to describe what he sees as very real, non-hypothetical differences between his own sense of justice and what he believes to be Omar Bakri's sense; it's not surprising that he wavers between realis and irrealis forms.

You'll encounter this sort of thing frequently. You don't want to emulate it; but you shouldn't be particularly troubled by it, either.

Comment: +1  - Despite my irrealis misgivings that you're aware of! :D

Comment: The so-called 0-3 conditionals name common patterns that do actually exist in English. Only a poor teacher will introduce them as _rules_ -  whereby if you have x verb form in the protasis, then you must have y verb form in the apodosis. I think the most useful approach is summarized in this section on conditionals in _The English Verb_ (Lewis, p149): "_The explanation of the use of a form in a conditional sentence is exactly the same as that of its occurrence in any other utterance. The underlying principle behind this is that each main verb phrase is treated independently._"

Comment: @Shoe I have three primary objections to the n-conditionals:  1) They're taught as if the patterns were monosemous. 2) They're taught in a manner which leads learners to believe that the list of patterns is exhaustive. 3) The names are not only meaningless in themselves but also obscure the underlying rationality of the constructions.

Comment: @StoneyB. Yes, the labels are not descriptive but they are the ones that are typically used in EFL materials. This is why so many questions here and on ELU refer to them. They are a convenient shorthand for the very common structures they refer to. It is up to teachers and publishers to ensure that learners are not led to believe these are the only ways to express conditions.

Comment: I recently had some students do a piece of writing on the Challenger disaster. It was helpful to be able to tell them that speculations on how the disaster could have been avoided used a structure typically designated Conditional 3 (_If the weather had not been so cold, the O-rings would not have disintegrated_). If they needed more practice in this structure, they could find plenty of exercises online under this term.

Comment: @Shoe I'm not arguing with its use as a pedagogical device; but it creates a lot of confusion when the student is ready to move beyond getting a handle on conditionals to actually using conditionals in ways which the model does not address. That confusion prompts most of the questions we're called on to address.

Comment: @StoneyB. I agree, but it is true of much of what we teach our students - moving from the simplistic to the real world. The same could be said, for example, of the confusion caused when students learn that we can use the present continuous for an action that is neither in the present nor continuous. I do feel in this case, however, that it is preferable to help learners move on from what they currently know to a more nuanced understanding, rather than imply that their teachers have been feeding them rubbish.

Comment: @Shoe But it *is* rubbish, just like the rubbish that native speakers are taught about never beginning a sentence with a conjunction or ending one with a preposition. It may be useful rubbish. It may even be necessary rubbish (but I think there are better ways of teaching conditionals). But it's harmful rubbish if you don't make clear from the outset that it's just a starting point which will eventually be superseded.

Comment: @StoneyB. It certainly is rubbish to do as I stated in my first comment above: namely, to claim that if you have x verb form in the protasis, then you must have y verb form in the apodosis. But I don't believe it is rubbish to teach the numbered conditionals as common patterns to express common meanings. I  would say that this knowledge will be enhanced rather than superseded. I'm going out in a minute but will check back tomorrow to see if you want to continue in chat. By the way, I'm not sure that your analogy with conjunctions and prepositions holds up here.

Comment: I'd be delighted to continue in Chat -- whyn't you just ping me when you're free? I drift in and out many times per day.

Comment: @StoneyB. I've got some time to chat now, if you are still interested.